# Are Selection or Insertion sort useful outside of academic environments?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort, selection-sort

Do these sorting algorithms have any use in real world application?

Or is it just a basic example of sorting algorithm with n^2 complexity?

Can anyone give some example of its usage?

Comment: define "real world" applications

Comment: Example of its usage: teaching efficiency and sorting algorithms to computer science students

Comment: "real world applications" like where do people use it? In which case should we use it? Is there any software or any module the use this?

Comment: @cricket_007 well we know that. Thats why i put this question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @Vhortex,  and cricket_007: if you don't care, that's fine. The question is valid and if you have not thought about it, that's fine.

Comment: @Aravind don't care? What part of my comment is wrong. Everything will be buried under a library of DLL. when was the last time you told an end user to compile his own sorting algorithm when using for example excel. Did you ever tell Bob who is a typist to "BOB, open your compiler and go to line 172, run the Spellcheck with the 5 parameters and load ABC.DLL while you are at it"?

Comment: @Aravind the question is "Do these sorting algorithms have any use in real world application?". Not "What are these sorting algorithms".

Comment: @Vhortex: I agree, but curiosity never hurt anybody. And they are used in implementations because they are fast for small inputs, that's the point.

Comment: Again the question is if he can see it on the "real world", fact is, you wont. it will be hidden, replaced with a better implementation. It won't appear as it is. The way Academic designed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insertion sort is one of the fastest sorting algorithm for sorting very small arrays.

In practice, many quicksort / mergesort implementations stop when the subarrays to sort is below certain threshold, and insertion sort is then used for these small arrays.

---

Selection sort is rarely used in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Insertion sort is actually pretty fast for small input sizes, due to the small hidden constants in its complexity. Upto some size, insertion sort is faster than merge sort.

Thus, for many popular sorting algorithms, when the array size becomes very small, insertion sort is employed.

**Bottomline:** A O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm may be faster in practise than a O(N*logN) algorithm for sufficiently small sized inputs, owing to the hidden constants.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, insertion sort is widely used in industrial applications. That's mainly dues ot the fact that several popular C++ standard libraries such as [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h) and [libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm) implement `sort` routine as a combination of insertion sort and depth-limited quicksort.

The idea is that insertion sort works very fast on nearly-sorted arrays, while for a straightforward implementation of quick sort sorted input leads to the worst-case behavior. Therefore the combined algorithm first applies a quicksort-like algorithm to partially sort the input, and then finished off with a call to insertion sort.

In [libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm) insertion sort is also used for sorting by default if the input size is small enough (but larger than five elements, as sizes <= 5 are handled as special cases).

Answer (score 0):

HP / Microsoft std::sort() is [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), quicksort with a depth parameter that  switches to heapsort if the depth becomes too deep.

HP / Microsoft std::stable_sort() is a type of [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). It uses insertion sort to create groups of 32 sorted elements, then uses bottom up merge sort to merge the groups.

On a side note, top down merge sort is not used in any common library that I'm aware of. Instead the common library versions for both internal (memory) and external (disk) merge sorts are all variations of bottom up merge sort (like timsort). Yet in a classroom environment or on web site articles, you see more examples of top down merge sort than bottom up merge sort.