# Big O(n logn) is not preferable over the O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, space-complexity, code-complexity

Any Algorithms example when do we prefer Big O(n^2) time complexity over the O(n logn)? 
I have seen this question somewhere but did not find answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any cases where you would prefer a higher big-O time complexity algorithm over the lower one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179968/are-there-any-cases-where-you-would-prefer-a-higher-big-o-time-complexity-algori)

Comment: Is this about general reasons to pick a "slower" algorithms (in this case: yes, duplicate), or about an actual, real-world example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several reasons to choose an algorithm with a higher time complexity:

- Speed: The asymptotic complexity only applies to values of n greater than some n_0. Also, it assumes a certain machine underneath which only partially matches real machines with multiple levels of cache and constrained memory.
- Space: Some algorithms require more space than others, and thus become impossible to implement. Also, this may simply influence the speed on a real machine. For example, locality of references has influence on cache hits or misses, which is the reason why Quicksort performs better than Mergesort.
- Implementation complexity: In some cases the loss in performance is simply negligible, but the development time isn't.

Answer (score 8):

For a large problem, O(n log n) will always beat O(n^2). For a small problem, the constant factors hidden by the big-O notation may cause you to prefer the O(n^2) algorithm. For instance, the O(n log n) quicksort is faster than the O(n^2) insert sort, but some quicksort implementations switch to insert sort when the partitions get small (less than ten elements).

Comment: Very true, people tend to forget the lead-in sentence of all Big-O claims: "There is an `n0` so that for all `n > n0`...". Also, this `n0` can be surprisingly large.

Comment: Yes, a similiar question recently; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218322/are-selection-or-insertion-sort-useful-outside-of-academic-environments/35218436#35218436

Comment: Quicksort is O(n^2) in the worst-case (although it's fairly simple to avoid the worst-case inputs); but to use a different example, quicksort often performs better than actually O(n lg n) algorithms like heapsort and mergesort.

Answer (score 1):

Many naive O(n^2) algorithms are faster *on small inputs* than their more complicated O(n log(n)) brethren.

For example, the [GNU MP Bignum library](https://gmplib.org/) has a very highly optimized multiplication implementation. But for numbers made up of a couple dozen words it just uses schoolbook multiplication (the best threshold [depends heavily on the machine](https://gmplib.org/devel/thres/MUL_TOOM22_THRESHOLD.html)). In fact GMP [transitions through a whole sequence of fastest-around-size-X algorithms](https://gmplib.org/manual/Multiplication-Algorithms.html#Multiplication-Algorithms).

Answer (score -1):

One possibility - the O(n logn) algorithm is recursive, but you can program the O(n^2) iteratively, and your programming language that you must use does not support recursion.

"Preferred" is relative here BTW.  If the data-set was large enough, you COULD emulate recursion by using your own stack variable that you manipulate in a version of the "recursive" algorithm that was implemented iteratively (we had to do that exercise in Guy Steele's Comparative Programming class at CMU back-in-the-day).

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, all recursive algorithms can be rewritten as iterative algorithms, they just aren't always as simple and nice looking